# Updating Predictive Model to Forecast from Today’s Date

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model

I have a historical dataset with four numerical columns: c1, c2, c3, and c4. Column c4 is calculated and represents the number of days between the active date and the closed date. I have created a model that predicts the value of c4 based on the values of c1, c2, and c3. However, I have encountered a problem. For example, if the model predicts 90 days and the active date was October 1st, 2022, 90 days have already passed but the prediction will still be 90 because the input data is the same.

Is it possible to create a model, add a calculation, or add additional datapoint(s) so that it gives me the value of predicted c4 from today’s date?

Thank you for your help.